# Redirect a website from http to https

Tags: apache, redirect, http-redirect

I am currently running a website written in struts. I am using Apache web server and using AJP to ProxyPass my web application to Apache tomcat server.

My server is Ubuntu server hosted in Amazon. I was able to run my web application successfully using http.

Now I am planning to implement SSL for the above web application. I have completed all the SSL implementation steps and now I can **access my web application successfully using https** that is, https://{MY_APPLICATION_URL}

Now the issue is with: when user enter my application URL like http://{MY_APPLICATION_URL} or {MY_APPLICATION_URL}, I need to redirect and make them to only use https://{MY_APPLICATION_URL}. http access must not be there.

I found the following link: http://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html and **installed rewrite module** in apache server (through webmin). Then added the following lines in my application's virtual host (Edit directives).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Even after above redirecting, when user enters http://{MY_APPLICATION_URL} or {MY_APPLICATION_URL} it displays my apache server's default welcome page. However when I type https://{MY_APPLICATION_URL}, I was able to access my web application successfully.

Can anyone please guide me where I am doing wrong.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution helped me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.name/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope it'll be helpfull for you too.

Comment: no..its not working for me:( Have you enabled mod_rewrite module or rewrite module in apache?

Comment: Yep, in my httpd.conf (CentOS) i have the line like LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so ; Have you also configured VirtualHost for your domain listening to 443 port?

Comment: yes.. I have already configured my VirtualHost to listen 443 port. Hence I was able to access https://{MY_APPLICATION_URL} successfully. Now the problem is only with http://{MY_APPLICATION_URL} access.

Comment: And what about .htaccess ? Does it work? I mean whether it's processed or not.. Also i'd like to know what happens with my example ? Did you get the same reaction (redirecting to the apache sample page) ?

Answer (score 0):

Working with me on the server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Add it to a file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Or use php

```
<?php
function redirectTohttps() {
if($SERVER['HTTPS']!=”on”) {
$redirect= “https://”.$SERVER['HTTPHOST'].$SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header(“Location:$redirect”); } }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it in:

- Webmin > Config Webmin > SSl Config
- Check yes in > Redirect non-SSL requests to SSL mode?
- Reload browser and clear cache (Ctrl + Shift +R)