# Apache config issue - redirect all traffic to https using Apache

Tags: apache, config

I'm struggling tremendously with the concept of webservers. I will describe my desired solution and current situation as clear as possible.

I have an on-premise server, where Debian is running. I have installed several pieces of software on the server, including a full LAMP stack, Kibana, ThingsBoard etc. We got a public IP and recently acquired a domain, let's say apachenoob.com.

I can access my applications via a web browser at `<ip>:<port>` or `apachenoob.com:<port>`. However, I want those application to run over HTTPS, so I acquired a free SSL certificate with Certbot. Now `https://apachenoob.com` is working and showing the default Apache homepage.

What I want are a few things:

1. Instead of `apachenoob.com:9090` I want users and myself to go to
   thingsboard.apachenoob.com, or other URLS for other applications than ThingsBoard.

**MY SOLUTION**:
Add the following line to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Add the following `thingsboard.conf` to `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` (Debian):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName thingsboard.apachenoob.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine on

    ProxyPass    / http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090/

    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/file
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/key
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thingsboard.apachenoob.com
    Redirect / https://thingsboard.apachenoob.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thingsboard.apachenoob.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

2. I want to disable traffic to the IP (and optionally port number) or redirect everything to `https://apachenoob.com`
3. Less important: I developed an API using Python and Flask and got it to run over the MOD_WSGI module. But, it is also running over HTTP, where HTTPS is the goal.

For the first, I tried adding VirtualHosts, in seperate files and in the main apache2.conf, no result (as described in several posts). Someone even told me the application might have an own internal web server (HELP?!).

For the second, I tried redirecting rules (described [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-ip-address-to-domain-name-apache)), both in the main config and in seperate files, no result.

For the third, I haven't even begun trying things as I'm feeling lost in a swamp of apache.

By all means, if this makes no sense please tell me and I will try to clarify.

Comment: Hi, these all seem like like reasonable (and easily doable) requests, but some more clarifications are needed: first (1.): if you want want to go to `https://www.apachenoob.com/application2`, you can just type that in your browser address bar, but I guess that is not what you want? Can you explain like: "when I type <this> in my address bar , then <that> happens, but I want <something else> to happen, also <some other url> shows exactly what I want but I want that to be reachable using <some third url>...." you get what I mean.

Comment: Also, I suggest you configure one hostname per app: kibana,apachenoob.com, thingsboard.apachenoob.com, www.apachenoob.com ... It costs nothing and will be easier to maintain and split to different servers in the future. Btw, domain `apachenoob.com` is available, you can grab it and start writing a blog :)

Comment: @DusanBajic thanks for your reply. Here it goes: when I type www.apachenoob.com:9090 in my address bar, I see my ThingsBoard application running fine, but what I want instead, is to have to typ thingsboard.apachenoob.com (thanks for the tip). Also, when I type 12.345.678.90 (my IP) in my adress bar, I get the Apache default page. I want to (1) disable traffic directly to the IP or (2) redirect it to the domain name so it shows www.apachenoob.com in the adress bar. Hope this helps :)

Comment: OK,can you share your apache configuration (anything non-default that you added)?

Comment: I only added this: "ServerName apachenoob.com". It is identical to [this](https://www.linode.com/docs/assets/apache2.conf) except the "Mutex file" is commented out at mine.

Answer (score 0):

For point 1. you need something like this (put it in file named `thingsboard.conf` in folder `sites-enabled/` (add correct path to certificate/key):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName thingsboard.apachenoob.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile    ...
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ...

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9090/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thingsboard.apachenoob.com
    Redirect / https://thingsboard.apachenoob.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it's not working. Chrome error: `This site can’t be reached thingsboard.apachenoob.com's server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for ...`

Comment: Well, you also need to configure that new hostname in your DNS server (the same way as you did with `www.apachenoob.com`

Comment: I added thingsboard.apachenoob.com to the same IP, but couldn't add a port number in the DNS service. I tried to access the application, but sadly I can't.

Comment: You shouldn't add port to DNS, it just connects hostname to ip address. What happens in Chrome when you try  now (after adding DNS entry)?

Comment: After waiting a few moments I see the default debian Apache homeage (http, not https)

Comment: Oh, wait. When accessing https:// thingsboard.apachenoob.com, i see the app! But only in http. I get the warning message but i can access thingsboard. If i type http:// thingsboard.apachenoob.com, i still see the default landing page from debian apache.

Comment: Ok, we are progressing, but I dont get how can it be both "When accessing https://" and "But only in http."

Comment: When I type in "**https**:// thingsboard.apachenoob.com", I get this warning: [link](https://ibb.co/600s0Qc) (I blurred the domain name). When I click on **"Proceed to..."**, I can access my thingsboard app. When I type in "**http**://thingsboard.apachenoob.com, I get the default landing page from Apache Debian.

Comment: You need to have SSl certificate explicitly for full hostname `thingsboard.apachenoob.com`, you can not use the one for `www.apachenoob.com` or `just `apachenoob.com`

Comment: About `http`, do you want users redirected to `https` or you want your app to be available over plain http?

Comment: Ah, is see. Will do that asap. It is possible via letsencrypt/certbot right?

Comment: I would like to redirect it to https if possible.

Comment: Thanks, **https://** thingsboard.apachenoob.com is working! However, if I force type **http://** thingsboard.apachenoob.com, the default apache landing page is still visible.

Comment: Are there any other `.conf` files in `sites-enabled/` folder?

Comment: Yes. However, I managed to get it working. In addition to your snippet, I added ``LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`` to apache2.conf and ``<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thingsboard.apachenoob.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`` to the Virtual Host file and it works :). If formatting is wrong, this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483722/redirect-a-website-from-http-to-https?rq=1)